# A congruence involving Mersenne numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, examples-counterexamples, conjectures

Can you provide a proof or counterexample to the following claim ?

> Let $p$ be a prime number greater than two then :
>
> $$2^{2^{p-1}-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^p-1}$$

[Pari/GP implementation](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrsDU2tOblykzTyMlMK9HwzU_RMNIxiivQNdSM0zCK0wAxgEjT1tZQp6AoM69EQwlI5aYqacK4yfm5BfnFmSVAIU2gSQCdYRc2&lang=gp) .

I have tested this claim up to $5 \cdot 10^4$ .

I was searching for a counterexample using the following Pari/GP code :

```
MersenneFermat(lb,ub)={
forprime(p=lb,ub,
if(!(lift(Mod(2,2^p-1)^(2^(p-1)-1))==1),print(p)))
}
```

Comment: Yes, that finds primes, but it also finds Fermat pseudoprimes to base 2, also called Sarrus numbers or Poulet numbers. [A001567](https://oeis.org/A001567), eg 341, 561, 645, 1105, 1387, 1729

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Fermat's little theorem we know that $p\mid 2^{p-1}-1$ which means that $2^{p-1}-1=k\cdot p$.
Then, $2^{2^{p-1}-1}-1=2^{kp}-1=(2^p)^k-1=(2^p-1)(2^{p(k-1)}+2^{p(k-1)}+\ldots+1)$ which is a multiple of $2^p-1$ which is equivalent to what you ask.